# Rails Model Not Updating on Capistrano deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano

Alright so I've spent considerable amount of time with this and still can't find out what's wrong.

Here's whats going on: I've got a model reward.rb with a method X like this:

```
class Reward < ActiveRecord::Base
  def x
    puts "foo" # Method does something...
  end
end
```

The rails app is now on a production environment, in development, if you do

```
rails c
```

and then

```
>> r = Reward.new
>> r.x
"foo" # I.e it works...
```

now, if you go into the server and do

```
rails c
```

and then

```
>> r = Reward.new
>> r.x
NoMethodError: undefined method `x' for #<Reward:0x0000000561fa08>
```

If you check reward.rb in the same server you'll see the method's there, actually it's the first method in the file... so, as I can see Rails is not loading the latest code of the model when it loads the console...

I thought it might have something to do with Rails' cache but production.rb says:

```
MyApp::Application.configure do
  config.cache_classes = false     
  config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching             = false
  # SMTP settings and other stuff.. not related to caching...
end
```

And environment.rb:

```
# Load the rails application
require File.expand_path('../application', __FILE__)

# Initialize the rails application
MyApp::Application.initialize!
```

And application.rb:

```
module MyApp
  class Application < Rails::Application    
    config.encoding = "utf-8"    
    config.filter_parameters += [:password]
  end
end
```

So I've ran out of ideas... The app was deployed with capistrano, I'm using Rails 3.0.10.

**UPDATE**

Alright, so I figured out the problem, pretty silly to be honest, there was a models.bak folder inside app/ that someone created, on production the models were getting picked up from that folder

Answer (score 0):

Have you run database migrations on your deploy server?

You may need to set up a capistrano recipe to do this. I believe an out-of-date database schema could cause this error.

Comment: I believe the schema is up to date I'll check again though, thanks

Comment: Yeap, schema is up to date, any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A stupid question: have you checked the *reward.rb* file on the server? Is it the correct (new) version?

Comment: Yeap, as mentioned on the question, the reward.rb file onthe server does have the method in it

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart unicorn o what ever you have manually.

Comment: I believe the console has nothing to do with the server so I don't think that's the issue

Answer (score 0):

you have to do `rails c production` in order to run the production environment.